# Using Dynamic JQueryValidation and Adding Rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, checkbox

I am currently working on a website and validating my page using Jquery validation plugin. I want certain elements of the form to be validated depending on what checkbox combinations are checked when the user hits the submit button.

On my form I have a book selection list box, then right below it I have a Month selection box, then below that, a Day selection box. Below these list boxes are 3 checkboxes, let's call them Checkbox A, B, and C. When none of the A,B, C checkboxes are selected I want to make only the book list box required. I have my reasons for doing this.

Right now after reading some examples on dynamic validation I have code which I thought would work but is not. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious or doing it plain wrong.I feel like this should be easy and maybe I'm not understanding something. Below is my code.

```
<script>

        var _validator;

        $(function() {


            _validator = $('#bookFormID').validate({


                errorClass: "error",
                validClass: "valid",

                rules: {


                    bookListBox: {required: false},
                    months: {required: false},
                    days: {required: false},


                },

                messages: {
                    bookListBox: "Please select a workstation.",
                     months: "Please select a month.",
                    days: "Please select a day.",

                    },

                highlight: function(element){



                    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
                },

                success: function(element){


                    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');

                }

            });

            $('#submitbuttonID').click(function(e){


                if($('#checkboxA')[0].checked == false && $('#checkboxB')[0].checked == false &&
                              $('#checkboxC')[0].checked == false)
                {
                    $('#bookListBoxID').rules('add', "required");
                }

                if(_validator.form())
                {
                    $('#bookFormID').submit();
                }

            });


        });


        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#rules

Take a look at the second example:

```
$(".selector").validate({
  rules: {
    contact: {
      required: true,
      email: {
        depends: function(element) {
          return $("#contactform_email:checked")
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.